# Is more than a virtual dedicated server needed initially for a user-generated video sharing site?

Tags: video, storage

I'm building a hybrid flash and HTML5 user-generated video site. I'm a novice but have some more knowledgeable developers helping me. I've bought a virtual dedicated server with 30 GB of disk space and 500 GB of bandwidth. My expectation is that we'll get 1000 videos uploaded and 10,000 downloaded year 1. Each video will be 3-5 minutes long - not high def for the most part. We don't have much money to spend. Do I need to get a storage solution like S3 and a content delivery network like Cloudfront or will I probably be ok that first year just using the VDS?

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: You should consider moving this to serverfault.com.  This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Think not only about storage and bandwidth but consider concurrent connections/streaming  also, that is going to happen with your server. It should not kill your server. CDN is the good option if your client spread is throughout the globe, it will provide you the fast delivery. For [Higher End VPS](http://www.unichost.com/vps-hosting.php) you might want to consider UnicHost.com.